# Prevent BehaviorSubject data manipulation in component reflects in service

Tags: angular, service, rxjs, observable, clone

I am using a Shared Service to Share Data among different components. The Problem is when i am trying to use this service inside my component and filtering some data, the same change happening in the shared data too. How can i prevent that? I have used **tap** operator instead of map while subscribing, but it does't work. One more solution i have tried is **cloneDeep** from **lodash** library, that also not working.

**Shared Service**

```
export class SharedDataService {
    private treeReport = new BehaviorSubject<ResultModel>(null);

    constructor() { }

    updateTreeReport(newReport: ResultModel) {
        this.treeReport.next(newReport);
    }

    getTreeReport() {
        return this.treeReport.asObservable();
    }
}
```

**Component**

```
this.featureDetails$ = this.sharedService.getTreeReport().pipe(map(treeReport) => {
      treeReport.features = treeReport.features.filter(item => item._id == id)
      return treeReport
    }))
```

**What i have tried as follows**

**1.**

```
this.featureDetails$ = this.sharedService.getTreeReport().pipe(tap(treeReport) => {
          treeReport.features = treeReport.features.filter(item => item._id == id)
          return treeReport
        }))
```

**2.**

```
this.featureDetails$ = this.sharedService.getTreeReport().pipe(map(treeReport) => {
          treeReport.features = cloneDeep(treeReport.features.filter(item => item._id == id))
          return treeReport
        }))
```

Comment: What is the type of `featureDetails$` in the component?

Comment: @MichaelD Observable<ResultModel>

Comment: What other properties are on `treeReport`? How is it used - do you just need the filtered features, or do you need other properties too?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you mutate that data and the same reference is shared among all the consumers.

If you only want the filtered `features` array without altering the data everywhere, you could follow this approach:

```js
this.featureDetails$ = this.sharedService.getTreeReport().pipe(
    pluck('features'),
    map(features => features.filter(item => item._id == id))
);
```

[pluck](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/pluck).

`Array.prototype.filter` will **not mutate** the original array, but it will create a new one.

Also, beware that `Subject.asObservable()` creates a new observable whose source is the subject itself.

Comment: The original was returning the whole `treeReport` object. Are you sure the other properties aren't required?

Comment: @KurtHamilton Good question! I'm not sure about that. But if they are, I think it depends on how he plans to use them. My first suggestion would be to use one stream, from which he would select and combine properties as needed.

Comment: I agree. There are a couple of unknowns at the moment.

Comment: @KurtHamilton  tap and cloneDeep can do anything here?

Comment: As long as you're mutating the original structure(e.g `treeReport.features = ...`), you'll end up with the same undesired result.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by adding **cloneDeep** in the shared service.

```
getTreeReport() {
    return cloneDeep(this.treeReport.asObservable());
}
```

Each time it will return a cloned copy of observable

Comment: @ Andrei Gătej @KurtHamilton  Please share your thoughts about this

Comment: Where do you apply your filter? And why do you need create an observable in your component?

Comment: Filter is in the component. Observables are result of Asyc Data